# Replacing Invalid Data in a List Python

Tags: python

I have a bigger version of this problem, with multiple items in a list, I need to replace an invalid data for a valid data, and the wrong data is always in the same character position of the list (let's say its the position `[9:13]` like the example below), normally I would use the command `.replace`, but there are times that this data that I'm trying to replace also appears in a different character position (like `[0:3`]), but it actually belongs there. How can I do this without affect relevant data?

Replacing word for data in character `[9:13]`:

```
a = ["word word word" , "word data othr" , "word, data word"]
```

Output should be:

```
b = ["word word data" , "word data othr" , "word, data data"]
```

Comment: `if s[9:13] == "word": s[0:9] + "data" + s[13:]`

Comment: Then how would you know which instance of "word" to replace if it appears in different locations and you have multiple instances of "word" in a string?

Comment: In the real version of the problem there are numbers instead, and now and then although it seems unlikely they match. This position represents coordenates, other postions represents monetary value.

Comment: @Andreas NameError: name 's' is not defined - What am I missing? :S

Answer (score 0):

You should use split and regex:

```
import re

a = ["word word word" , "word data othr" , "word, data word"]
b = []
for string in a:
    new_words = []
    words = string.split(" ") # can also use nltk.word_tokenize
    for idx,word in enumerate(words):
        if re.match("word", word) and idx == (len(words) - 1): # can also use word == "word" instead of regex # can also do idx == 0 for position 0:3
            new_words.append("data")
        else:
            new_words.append(word)
    b.append(" ".join(new_words))
```

Comment: If the characters to replace are always in the same place and the same length (the characters you're replace are length 4 and the characters that you're substituting are length 4) then @Andreas implementation is easy and simple. However, if these conditions are not met then an implementation similar to mine is better.

Comment: Thanks @sebastian its working fine, if possible could u add more comments in the code? although its working as im a begginner in this I didn't understand whats the purpose of each line of code.